# Activate a Nebular Theme tab

Tags: angular, tabs, nebular

I am using the Nebular Theme component and will want to manually activate a particular tab with a button click. I can't find any information in their doc
https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/tabs/overview#nbtabsetcomponent

```
<nb-tabset>
  <nb-tab tabTitle="Search">xxxx</ng-tab>
  <nb-tab tabTitle="Add">yyyyy</ng-tab>
</nb-tabset>

<button (click)="ActivateTabAdd()">Add</button>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
<nb-tabset id="tabset" name="tabset" #tabset>
  <nb-tab tabTitle="Search" id="searchTab" name="searchTab" #searchTab >xxxx</ng-tab>
  <nb-tab tabTitle="Add" id="addTab" name="addTab" #addTab >yyyyy</ng-tab>
</nb-tabset>
<button (click)="ActivateTabAdd()">Add</button>
```

```
import { NbTabsetComponent, NbTabComponent } from '@nebular/theme/components/tabset/tabset.component';

@ViewChild("tabset") tabsetEl: NbTabsetComponent;
@ViewChild("addTab") addTabEl: NbTabComponent;

ActivateTabAdd(){
  this.tabsetEl.selectTab(this.addTabEl);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes why not

there is an `active` attribute for tab `nb-tab` which Specifies active tab

so you can handle this like

```
<nb-tabset>
  <nb-tab tabTitle="Search" active="{{setActiveSearch}}">xxxx</ng-tab>
  <nb-tab tabTitle="Add" active="{{setActiveAdd}}" >yyyyy</ng-tab>
</nb-tabset>
<button (click)="ActivateTabAdd()">Add</button>
```

and in TS file

```
setActiveSearch : boolean = false;
setActiveAdd: boolean = false;

ActivateTabAdd(){
this.setActiveAdd = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks..   i got it to work with <nb-tab tabTitle="Search" active="{{setActiveSearch}}">xxxx</ng-tab>

Comment: @El7or, please help me with more details to move forward with this case.